# How to allow letters only in VARCHAR2 column (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, constraints

I have a column "surname" in my Oracle SQL database.

> CREATE TABLE test (
>   id VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY,
>   surname VARCHAR2(10));

What should I add in the query above, to allow inserting only alphabetical characters in a "surname"?

Comment: I tried with: CHECK(surname LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'); but when I have an error "ORA-02290: check constraint (DBNAME.SYS_C00157564) violated" even if I insert 'Smith' as a surname :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a `CHECK constraint` in your table.

The following should suffice `CHECK (regexp_like(surname,'^[[:alpha:]]+$'))`. Where `[[:alpha:]]` is alphabet character class. Thus, only considers the alphabets.

Let's see a test case -

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST(
  2  surname VARCHAR2(10),
  3  CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (regexp_like(surname,'^[[:alpha:]]+$'))
  4  )
  5  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST values ('LALIT')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST values ('123')
  2  /
INSERT INTO TEST values ('123')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.CONSTRAINT_NAME) violated


SQL>
```

So far it works good. Let's check with `Alphanumeric` values.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('LALIT123')
  2  /
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('LALIT123')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.CONSTRAINT_NAME) violated


SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TEST
  2  /

SURNAME
----------
LALIT

SQL>
```

So, the `CHECK` constraint **ONLY** allows the `alphabets`.

Comment: Can I use this constraint again later in creating this table, just by writing only CONSTRAINT constraint_name ?

Comment: You mean you want to add the check constraint after creating the table? Yes you could do that using `ALTER` statement. `ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (column_name condition)`

Comment: I mean if I'd add just after the line `surname VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (regexp_like(surname,'^[[:alpha:]]+$')` a line `name VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT constraint_name` - would it work with the same "check" without typing it?

Comment: No, it won't work that way. You must explicitly write the constraint condition for each of them.

Comment: The one thing you might want to consider is that surnames can have apostrophes (') and dashes (-) in them at the very least. In which case you might want to use a slightly different regex, e.g., `^[A-Za-z''-]+$` (the reason for the double single quote is to escape it in an Oracle string). Also beware of foreign surnames with accent marks and the like in them!

Comment: Agreed, perhaps I ought to have left a comment under the OP